# How to convert a string from Beautiful Soup to utf-8 encoding

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, utf-8, beautifulsoup

I'm running a parser in python 2.7 that is taking a text field of xml code from a database and using Beautiful Soup to find and pull different tags in the xml. When I am pulling the  tags from an  tag in the xml and getting to the given text it is returning

```
<author>
<name>Josef Šimánek</name>
</author>

Josef \xc5\xa0im\xc3\xa1nek
```

when what it should look like is

```
Josef Šimánek
```

my relevant code is as follows:

```
rss = str(f)
soup = BeautifulSoup(rss)
entries = soup.findAll('entry')
for entry in entries:
  author = entry.find('author')

  if author != None:
      for name in author.findAll("name"):
          if(checkNull(name).find(",") != -1):
              name = checkNull(name).split(",",1)
              for s in name:
              print s
          else: 
              print name
```

As you can see the code pulls out and cycles through the different tags and if the name tag contains a comma separated list of names, then it splits and prints each individually.

```
def checkNull(item):
  if item != None:
    return item.text.rstrip()
  return " "
```

Also the check null function is just a helper method to see if the returned tag even contains any text at all as seen above.

I have tried encode, decode, and unicode functions in order to try and resolve the issue however none have succeded. Are there any other methods recommended that i could try to fix this?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? 
    >>> import json
    >>> print 'Josef \xc5\xa0im\xc3\xa1nek'.decode('utf-8')
    Josef Šimánek
    >>> print json.dumps('Josef \xc5\xa0im\xc3\xa1nek')
    "Josef \u0160im\u00e1nek"

Comment: @Chainik, he's probably on Windows and trying to print in the console.  Windows doesn't support UTF-8 well, and Python 2.7 doesn't support code page 65001, which is Windows' UTF-8 code page.  @Mazar, describing your environment and showing the error you get when using `.decode('utf8')` would help us help you.

Comment: Right, it did feel environmental, but I didn't check on Winblowz..

Answer (score 1):

`name` is a `BeautifulSoup.Tag` type not a string so you're probably getting a __repr__ of the object that's suitable for a terminal that doesn't support UTF-8 (`\xc5\xa0` is the Python byte sequence for the UTF-8 encoding of `š`). `name.text` is probably the value you actually want, which should be a Unicode string.

If you're using Windows, it's best to avoid printing to the console as its console doesn't easily support UTF-8. You could use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/win_unicode_console, but it's easier to just write your output to a file instead.

I've cleaned up your code a little to make it simpler (quick null checks) and to write your output to a UTF-8 encoded file:

```
# io provides better access to files with working universal newline support
import io
# open a file in text mode, encoding all output to utf-8
output_file = io.open("output.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")

rss = str(f)
soup = BeautifulSoup(rss)
entries = soup.findAll('entry')
for entry in entries:
  author = entry.find('author')

  # If not null or not empty
  if author:
      for name in author.findAll("name"):
          # .text contains the actual Unicode string value
          if name.text:
              names = name.text.split(",", 1)
              # If string contained a comma, you'll have two elements in a list
              # else you'll just have the 1 length list
              for flname in names:
                  # remove any whitespace on either side
                  output_file.write(flname.strip() + "\n")

output_file.close()
```